# Loopback 3 and hook for REST API headers

Tags: javascript, node.js, rest, loopbackjs, loopback4

I have a legacy app which uses loopback 3 and exposes REST API and I wanna get my JWT token from the incoming requests from the clients. I wrote a hook for getting access to the **req** object to access the token.

```
Object.keys(app.dataSources).forEach((name: string) => {
    if (camelCase(name) === name) {
        app.dataSources[name].connector.observe('before execute', (ctx, next) => {
            if (!ctx.req.uri) return next(); 
            Object.keys(ctx.req).forEach(function(key) {
                console.log(key, ctx.req[key]);
            }); 
        });
    }
});
```

**Route definition**

```
accepts: [
    {arg: 'codeValue', type: 'string', required: false, http: {source: 'query'}},
    {arg: 'codeId', type: 'string', required: false, http: {source: 'query'}}
]
```

**The output when the above hook executes**

```
method GET
uri http://localhost:8010/api/v1/code/100
qs { codeValue: '' } <<== Issue 1
json true
form undefined
headers undefined  <<== Issue 2
timeout undefined
```

**Following are issues as highlighted above:**

- Even though I have specified query param **codeId**, it is not mapped in **req** object
- The headers in the **req** is coming as **undefined**

**Curl command**

```
curl -H "codeId: TS01" -H "codeValue: 'TS 01" http://localhost:8081/api/v1/code/100
```

We have plans to move to loopback to version 4, but is a long term process. Any pointers is highly appreciated.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

*Hello from the LoopBack team*

Based on the following snippet in your code, I am assuming you are using loopback-connector-rest (or a similar connector) to call APIs of another backend service.

```js
app.dataSources[name].connector.observe('before execute'
```

Please note that `before execute` hook is called for *outgoing* requests made by your model methods.

To access the *incoming* request object, you need to create a remote hook instead (see [Remote hooks](https://loopback.io/doc/en/lb3/Remote-hooks.html) in our docs).

```
app.remotes().before('**', (ctx, next) => {
  if (!ctx.req.url) return next(); 
  Object.keys(ctx.req).forEach(function(key) {
    console.log(key, ctx.req[key]);
  }); 
});
```

(Note that the incoming request does not have `req.uri` property, you should use `req.url` instead.)

Comment: Hi Miroslav. Thank you very much and this resolved a long standing issue.